# Merkletree proof

Tags: solidity, javascript, nft, merkle

in js i want array like this let arr = ["a","b","c"]
but i am getting arr = ['a','b','c']
is there any way to do this?

Notes : it's for merkletree to send proof through frontend

Answer (score 1):

In JS there's no different between " and ', these just use to display strings to the user, but data stored in the variable does not contain either.